# No se muestra el Logo en el Toolbar

Tags: android-studio

no se donde puedo tener el problema, he puesto en el `MainActivity.java` el siguiente codigo, y el logo no se muestra.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.barra_icon);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle( "Prueba Titulo" );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En android studio en el margen izquiedo si aparece el icono, pero luego en el emulador no, falta algun codigo por poner ?

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.MainActivity">

<com.SoCu.Docu_Adif.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundMenuColor="#0099cc"
    app:backgroundNotifications="@color/colorAccent"
    app:icon_height="30dp"
    app:icon_width="30dp"
    app:item_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:item_colorSelected="#ffffff"
    app:item_textColor="#ffffff" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr el efecto que quieres haremos lo siguiente. Primero vamos a usar un elemento conocido como toolbar para dar un mejor soporte a este elemento. Seguiremos la siguiente logica

1) Cambiamos el estilo de la aplicacion a uno que no use un action bar por defecto.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

2) Implementamos el elemento toolbar dentro de nuestro layout (observa que cambia de posicion donde ubicas el elemento toolbar)

main_acitivity_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        />

    <com.SoCu.Docu_Adif.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundMenuColor="#0099cc"
        app:backgroundNotifications="@color/colorAccent"
        app:icon_height="30dp"
        app:icon_width="30dp"
        app:item_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:item_colorSelected="#ffffff"
        app:item_textColor="#ffffff" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</LinearLayout>
```

3) Le decimos a nuestra vista que usaremos este toolbar como actionBar y procedemos a configurarlo con los elementos deseados (Te paso la clase con los imports y el metodo onCreate, el resto lo dejas igual)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.SoCu.CirDocu;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.SoCu.Docu_Adif.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView;
import com.SoCu.Docu_Adif.extras.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    HorizontalScrollMenuView horizontal_menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Titulo Aqui");
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        horizontal_menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        horizontal_menu.addItem("Telefonos", R.drawable.menu1_icon,true);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Navegador GPS", R.drawable.menu2_icon );
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 2", R.drawable.menu3_icon );
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 3", R.drawable.menu4_icon );
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 4", R.drawable.menu5_icon );
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 5", R.drawable.menu6_icon );
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 6", R.drawable.menu7_icon );
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 7", R.drawable.gps3_icon);


        horizontal_menu.showItems();

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                horizontal_menu.setItemSelected(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });

        horizontal_menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

Espero esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Hola @Jhon, perdona por no responder antes, no recibo notificaciones de nuevas respuestas, he probado con el código que me dices, y no funciona, bueno sí que funciona, pero no es lo que intento hacer, con ese código lo que me cambia es la flecha, pero lo que intento es añadir junto a la flecha otro icono, o más bien un logo porque no quiero que tenga ninguna función, solo que se muestre entre la flecha y el texto del Toolbar.

Comment: Intentaste cambiar tu mipmap por un SVG como te mencione en la segunda parte de la respuesta?

Comment: Editare la respuesta, mira como lo hago.

Comment: Mejor porque la pagina esta en ingles y me cuesta entenderla, el icono que intento poner es un PNG, y he visto en esa pagina que tambien pueden ser PSD, pero lo estoy intentando con el PNG ya que ha llegado a mostrarse pero en otro lugar. no se si por el tipo de menu que tengo creado se puede complicar, he editado el primer post y he puesto en **styles.xml** y en **activity_main.xml**, pero mira donde me muestra error, http://funkyimg.com/i/2CdZp.png no se si al cambiar algo del **styles.xml** me dejaria de funcionar otra cosa.

Comment: Cuando cambias tu styles.xml como te mostre a un stylo que no tenga por defecto un action bar, te toca en todos los acitivities hacer lo que te mostre, que es el uso del toolbar, lo cual es una mejor practica porque te da mas flexibilidad. De resto no te debe dar problemas. Revisa los imports en tu acitivity para que el toolbar que estas importando en tu acitivyt sea el mismo del xml. Por favor, muestrame el error que te sale en toolbar (pasando el mouse por encima de esta linea y esperando un momento)

Comment: Perdona Jhon, he tenido problemas con Android Studio, te dejo una captura del codigo que se ha cambiado porque tambien daba error, y el mensaje que sale al pasar el raton http://funkyimg.com/i/2CijK.png

Comment: El error es lo que te comento. El import que has usado es incorrecto. Busca dentro de tus imports (en la parte superior del activity) android.widget.toolbar y borrarlo. Posteriormente importa nuevamente el la libreria que usa el toolbar pero asegurate de importar la libreria correcta que vendria siendo: android.support.v7widget.Toolbar (Te recomiendo siempre usar los componentes que vengan de la libreria support)

Comment: vale, ahora si se ha quitado el error, pero no funciona la aplicación, no llega ni a iniciarse en el emulador, tengo que desactivar el codigo **Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);** y el **setSupportActionBar(toolbar);** entonces funcina en el emulador, pero claro no aparece el icono

Comment: Cambiaste en el styles el codigo que te dije? Por favor comparte el log del error cuando la inicias  y no quites el codigo que te describo arriba. Esa es la solucion y si esta saliendo algun error es porque algo estamos haciendo mal.

Comment: No estoy en casa y te respondo desde el movil, no se como saldra, te puse en el primer post el styles que tengo, hay para que funcione como lo tengo, hay un `<style>` con el codigo  **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**, no se si puedo añadir otro `<style>` con el codigo **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**, luego lo vuelvo a poner y te pongo el error que sale, dime si puedo poner en el sytle.xml el codigo que me pones mas el que yo tengo puesto.

Comment: Ya he cambiado el styles y como me temia no funciona, mira la imagen adjunta para que veas como esta el styles.xml, y luego como aparace el menu, sin barra http://funkyimg.com/i/2CnpS.png, por lo poco que entiendo creo que por un lado estoy mostrando el toolbar y por otro lo estoy quitando con el **NoActionBar**

Comment: Si gustas sube el proyecto a un repo en git e intento arreglarlo, porque me esta costando mucho arreglaro con los comentarios jejejee. Si usar el stylo no action bar debes usar el elemento toolbar para agregarlo de manera programatica.

Comment: Me ha costado, es el primero que subo, espero que este bien, te he puesto el link en el primer post (desde Android Studio he puesto exportar a zip, y el contenido de ese archivo es el que he subido porque la carpeta donde tengo el proyecto, pesa mucho mas) ya me diras si esta bien.

Comment: Solucionado, revisa la respuesta editada. Agradezco tu punto y respuesta correcta al finalizar jajaaj

Comment: Estupendo ya lo veo muchas gracias, el punto te lo unas respuestas mas atras, y a todas estas tambien, voy a probarlo, los imports los tenia, pero como seguia haciendo pruebas, lo deje como lo tenia al principio para que vieses el proyecto como estaba antes de editarlo y al desactivar algun codigo se anulo esos imports, Jhon si no te importar por favor quita la imagen que has puesto en el post ;) lo que si he visto que en eso no me percate es que el <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> lo has puesto arriba en el activity_main.xml

Comment: okey ya la edito.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73162/discussion-between-socu-and-jhon-fredy-trujillo-ortega).